# Parenting mesh with Bones > Error: failed to find solution for one or more bones

Tags: rigging

Hey this is my first rigging experience and I tried rigify and now the old method and I get stuck in the same area basically, a little further with rigify but in the end the same issue.

Here's a video of my issue ->
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FkeLQzcQyQU&feature=youtu.be

Updated Issue (for those that don't want to watch the video):
- Bone heat weighting failed to find one or more bone
- Now in riggify it finds the head neck and spine bones, but not the limbs
- In the old fashion method it finds no bones
- I have the limbs detached but still all acting as 1 mesh
- My friend said I need to actually have each limb have its on mesh.
- This character I'm using was imported into blender via .obj file from magicavoxel

- here's the file ->  http://www.filedropper.com/toonedenfrommagicavoxel

*After removing duplicated vertices, I still get the same issue when using riggify:

[image]

only the mid bones work and not the limbs.

Comment: The voxel mesh is probably non-manifold. There will be duplicate vertices or geometry issues inside probably. Check the duplicate question and please don't post question as a video with no info here, it takes time to watch it and the link could get broken.

Comment: Updated my question (people get cranky on this site)

Comment: You don't have to have each limb separate, that's not good actually. The rigify differs because it generates bones at different positions, which might by luck work. There are certainly problems with the mesh. Could you share the file somewhere so people can inspect? That would help big time.

Comment: heres the file: http://www.filedropper.com/toonedenfrommagicavoxel

Comment: Ok, you have duplicate vertices. You can check this with Select>Non-manifold in editmode. To fix it go into editmode(Tab), select everything (A) and remove doubles (Mesh>Vertices>Remove_Doubles). That should fix it.

Comment: Ok so I did what you suggested, but before I start the rigging process again, would you advise using riggify?

Comment: That depends what animation you need, rigify generates rather complicated rig with lots of features. It gives you stretch and also inverse kinematic controls. If you only need to pose the character or do simple animation go with simple rig.

Comment: it failed to work again it only does the spine neck and head and no limbs, heres a pic:  http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2rxwieq&s=8#.Vc6FyflVgqM